# Write a sum() function that takes an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here...
This code is from eloquent javascript and it works fine

```js
function sum(array) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let value of array) {
    total += value;
  }
  return total;
}
```

And this is what I wrote for the exercise but returns NaN..

```js
function sum(numArray) { 
  let add = 0;
  for (let a = 0; a <= numArray.length; a++) {
  let addIndex = numArray[a];
    add += addIndex;
  } 
  return add;
}
```

Comment: What values are actually in that array? I suspect that not everything in there is a 'number'.

Answer (score 4):

Your `for` loop goes out of array indexes. You have to use:

```
a < numArray.length
```

Instead of:

```
a <= numArray.length
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply add `undefined` to `add`, because you run the index count to long.

```
for (let a = 0; a <= numArray.length; a++) {
//                 ^                         wrong, takes last index + 1
```

```js
function sum(numArray) { 
  let add = 0;
  for (let a = 0; a < numArray.length; a++) {
    let Addindex = numArray[a];
    add += Addindex;
  } 
  return add;
}

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, my concern was that my loop wont complete if its < than the length of my array.

Comment: maybe you miss the point that indices are zero based. the array index starts with zero and the length is the maximum index plus one. with non sparse arrays, you have the same amount of items as the length shows.

Comment: @Ola-Juwon Arrays are 0 indexed, so if you have an array `[a, b, c, d]` the buckets are 0-3 but the length is of 4

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of this `a <= numArray.length`. Change it to `a < numArray.length`. This case a[5] that is the 6th element or the element at 5th index is undefined as the array starts from 0 index. So it will add an `undefined` with previously added number and hence it will be `NaN`

```js
function sum(numArray) {
  let add = 0;
  for (let a = 0; a < numArray.length; a++) {
    let Addindex = numArray[a];
    add += Addindex;
  }
  return add;
}

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Comment: Oh gotcha, forgot my array starts from index 0 and would run one more time extra if set to = the length of the argument array which the index doesn't exist in the argument array. I was concentrating on my length property and forgot the index of the array starts from 0 and not 1.... Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an out-of-bounds error.  In your `for` loop, you can change it to:

`for (let a = 0; a < numArray.length; a++) {`

OR

`for (let a = 0; a <= numArray.length - 1; a++) {`

The latter works too, but is harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a function that has two parameters, an array and a callback function that adds the values of the array like

```
function forEach(array, arrayAdder){
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++)
    arrayAdder(array[i]) ;
}
```

We can now initialize both the array and the sum like

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], sum = 0;
```

After that we pass it into the function like this

```
forEach(array, function(number){
    sum += number ;
});
```

Then print the answer

```
console.log(sum);
```